# Проблема с работой метода hasNextLine

Tags: java

Хочу написать программу которая проверяет, ввёл ли пользователь именно строку. Попробовала вот так, но она читает и числа в том числе, почему, что не так?)
public class HasNextLine {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // write your code here
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Введите строку:");

        if (input.hasNextLine()){
            String s = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(s.toLowerCase());
            System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
            System.out.println(s.substring(1, 5));
            System.out.println(s.indexOf("hello"));
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Извините, вы ввели не строку");
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: Сделайте просто на основе перехвата ошибки работы со строкой

Comment: Наверное, потому что линия - это строка, т.е. даже "8" - String

Comment: Хорошо, если там строка, то любое преобразование как с цифрой, например простое преобразование в число, создаст исключение

Comment: nextLine() возвращает строку (String), а к строке можно привести все, что угодно, в т.ч. число. посему нужно понимать, что именно вы хотите получить? а если я ввел не число, а , к примеру, дату? или просто восклицательный знак? это корректно? что именно вы проверить пытаетесь?

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант. Я только не помню какое исключение будет

```
String s = input.nextLine();
Boolean _is_string = false;
try {
   int _t = Integer.ValueOf(s);
   _is_string = false;
} catch (NumberException e) {
   _is_string = true;
}
```